# How can i render all html elements in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to render all html elements from a view to get data enclosed within it.(i.e.within paragraph tag "Good morning" and another paragraph tag "Have a nice day" if  i render  paragraph tag than i'll get "Good morning Have a nice day".) So if any body have any idea regarding this please share.

Comment: the below link has the answer you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314951/how-to-render-encoded-tags-as-proper-html-rather-than-text

Answer (score 0):

if you like to show output with html tags
then
try this

---

```
&lt; for less-than
&gt; for greater-than
&amp; for &
```

---

or 
htmlencode

Comment: Thanks Vikrant...but i wanna something different.Its regarding Rendering the tags and you are saying about displaying tags. Anyways thanks for co-operate.