# How to render HTML element from encoded HTML string in View?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am reading the contents of the blog post from a text file, it’s in HTML format and I want to show them on page as rendered HTML, but it’s not happening. All it's showing is simple text with HTML tags etc. in place.

I have tried three possible ways I know to make it work but all of them are showing not rendered HTML:

```
<section id="content">
    @Server.HtmlDecode(content[2])
    @content[2]
    @MvcHtmlString.Create(content[2])
    @Html.Raw(content[2])
</section>
```

content[2] contains HTML text:

```
"&lt;p itemprop=\"articleBody\" style=\"font-size:1.5em;line-height:1.467em;font-family:georgia, 'times new roman', times, serif;text-align:left;\"&gt;The movie, which tells the story of the way the small-market Oakland Athletics used outside-the-box statistical analysis to compete successfully against talent-rich competition, resonated with Snedeker, who is not the longest, straightest or most accurate hitter in golf.&lt;/p&gt
```

Which is shown as:

```
<p itemprop="articleBody" style="font-size:1.5em;line-height:1.467em;font-family:georgia, 'times new roman', times, serif;text-align:left;">The movie, which tells the story of the way the small-market Oakland Athletics used outside-the-box statistical analysis to compete successfully against talent-rich competition, resonated with Snedeker, who is not the longest, straightest or most accurate hitter in golf.</p>
```

If the problem is because that the saved content is doesn’t have actually opening close braces from `<` & `>` but rather they have their ascii codes, show how can I stop it from happening as it’s just a simple form with text area where I enter this content (using `Kendo UI` `Editor`) and after posting when I receive this in my controller it has ascii codes instead of actual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of : [How to render encoded tags as proper HTML, rather than text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314951/how-to-render-encoded-tags-as-proper-html-rather-than-text)

You can use Server.HtmlDecode(...) function on server side to set the Model property before passing the model to view, perhaps inside a controller/helper and then use @Html.Raw(...) inside the view.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<section id="content">
    @Html.Raw(content[2])
</section>
```

That should stop the razor view engine html encoding your html.

Comment: Have tried `@Html.Raw(content[2])`, but no effects, all three showing the same results.