# How can I make HTML elements stored as C# strings display properly?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, blazor

I have some HTML code that is stored in a C# string. I would like it to display as text rather than HTML code. Here is some sample code:

```
@page "/page"
@using System
@using System.Net

@{
    var link = "<a href='https://apple.com'>Link</a>"
}

<h1>Page</h1>

@WebUtility.HtmlDecode(link)
```

I am using Blazor (not MVC) and I have tried using the HtmlDecode method as recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314951/how-to-render-encoded-tags-as-proper-html-rather-than-text) question. I would like the link to display as such:

[link](https://apple.com)

but it displays as:

```
<a href="https://apple.com">link</a>
```

I am having the same problem with other HTML elements too. Does anyone know how I can make it display correctly?

Comment: `@((MarkupString)link)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MarkupString`

```
@((MarkupString)link)

@{
    string link = "<a href='https://apple.com'>Link</a>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved an Html. Then try using @variableName, instead of using HTML helpers or Razor helpers

```
@page "/page"
@using System
@using System.Net

@{
    var link = "<a href='https://apple.com'>Link</a>"
}

<h1>Page</h1>

@link
```